# Coldfusion 8 Cookies disappearing mid-session with IE8

Tags: cookies, coldfusion, internet-explorer-8, coldfusion-8

I am dealing with a ticketing system that was written about 10 years ago using Coldfusion 8.  When a user is authenticated and logins, the user's information about his ID is saved in CF cookies, and the site uses those cookies to fill it the user's ID, name, etc. when the user is filling out tickets.

This application works fine in Internet Explorer 6.0  However we are slowly migrating to Internet Explorer 8, so there are some users here that already started using IE8 fulltime.  We've been getting complaints from some of these IE8 users, in which mid-session, the cookies are lost/become null, and the user can't complete the tickets.  Users are able to login just fine, but sometimes in mid-session, errors like "NAME UNDEFINED" appear.  They don't seem to be isolated to particular tickets because I've looked at all the complaints we have, and they're discovered in all sorts of tickets.  I check the logs/screenshots and sure enough, the cookie for the employee ID is null.  I've searched all over the web and I can't find good fixes for this.

I thought about converting cookies to session variables, but that would be a massive undertaking and require a lot of testing.

Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error you listed indicates that the data is missing from the session scope, not the cookie scope.  Are you having problems with sessions dropping, or cookie data disappearing?

Comment: I'm having problems with cookie data disappearing.  I'm using HTTPWatch and monitoring the cookies.  It's always ONE cookie that disappears/becomes null, but the other cookies stay fine.  Also, this issue only happens in IE8... users that are using IE6 don't report this problem to me.  The cookies already have expires = NEVER so I don't think it's an issue of cookies expiring..?

Comment: I wish I was using ColdFusion 8 ten years ago :)

Comment: Hahaha. Good point, Ciaran. 10 years is about 6 years off.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I meant to write that it's currently on Coldfusion 8.  I'm not sure what version the people before me were using when they developed this...

Answer (score 1):

Any chance the domain is changing?  You could be switching between www.servername.com and servername.com?  Unless you were writing domain cookies a change in the domain would cause the written for one domain cookies to be unaccessible from another. You can enable domain cookies in your Application.cfm or Application.cfc file.  Either set `<cfset this.setDomainCookies = true />` in Application.cfc or set the `setDomainCookies="true"` attribute on your `<cfapplication />` tag.  This will write cookies accessible from any subdomain.

Have the cookies expired?  You can set an expiration date for the cookie.  Perhaps it is expiring before the user's session expires?

Have you tried using the IE development toolbar to track the cookies?  You can use it to view cookies set for your site.

Comment: I've been using HTTPWATCH to try to monitor the cookies. 

In the code, all the cookies were set as expires = NEVER.  The weird thing is, when I check a user's session in HTTPWATCH, only *one* of the cookies, the employee's ID becomes NULL.  All the other cookies (employee name, etc.) still have their correct values there.

I'm pretty sure we're not switching domain names...

Answer (score 0):

In one of my application , our users are facing the same issue.It started all of sudden without any change in code.We suggest them to clear cache and tr-try and it works.But i need to know the root cause and its fix. 
Thank you